# Express with PHP-Like Folders

Tags: node.js, express

Instead of just using Express for single-page-sites and web applications, I've recently been trying to use express to replace a php Intranet site, where the site has many different pages and some of those pages are just intended to be totally different from others on the same site.

As I develop web pages on Express, there's one aspect (and only one) of php I kind of miss and that is:

With php you could easily group all static-files related to a particular web page into one folder with the server-side-scripting.

For example, sometimes a page I create has static files and views that are not going to be needed by other pages in the entire site, and for pages like this, I like to just put all the images, client-side-javascripts, css, and server-side-scripting into a single folder. Later, if I need to edit this page, I can go right-click on that folder and open all related files (client-side and server-side) in my text-editor at once.

With Express, I have to create a route in one place, put static files in a folder some other place and create views in yet another place. Later when I want to open up all the files related to the page, I have to go to multiple places to get all those files tabbed into my text-editor.

With php, there was no need to create a route. By simply placing an index.php file into a folder the route was created. Then, placing all page-related resources into that same folder was no problem for php.

I am no fan of PHP; I've never liked it as a scripting language. Yet, every once in a while I miss certain aspects of it. This is one of those aspects.

Has anyone published an app.js file where, during first launch, it recursively scans the application's folders auto creating routes based on the fact that a folder contains an index.js file in it? Also, such a script would also have to make all other files in these folders static, except for server-side-resource files like views and server-side scripts.

I'm not even sure this is a good idea, but I'm curious if anyone has attempted to build something on top of express that acts similar to what I'm describing.

Comment: Did you try to use middlewares? can exactly do that. maybe even further.

Comment: @LonnieBest It is possible to create base app and mount another app to it. In my base app i setup everything like view engine, cookies, sessions, users actions like login logout,etc. and then using `app.use('/bla', require('my-other-app.js')); i mount another-exppress-app into this base. in another-exppress-app i only setup routes,views,serve public assets, etc.(the rest is taken care of by base app),so only things that are related to this route(/bla).Or you could use a build system and do it the same way as you would in php but that i think would need a bit of work to set up but still doable.

Comment: @Molda Do the sub-express-app-instances you're creating also get instantiated when the app is initially launched (like the base-express-app is)? I want to avoid creating instances on a hit-by-hit basis.

Comment: @LonnieBest yes sure, once you start your app all of the mounted apps start as well

Comment: @Molda If one of your sub-apps has a coding error, does it bring down all other apps? I'm trying to achieve php like script independence too, while having express speed.

Comment: @LonnieBest yes it would affect all apps. Once you start it it actualy acts as one app.